# Regex repeated lines

Tags: regex, regex-group

Suppose I have this String:

```
Speaker 1:
Lorem ipsum
Speaker 1:
This is text
Speaker 1:
Another one
Speaker 2:
Yadda Yadda
Speaker 1:
Text
Speaker 2:
New text
```

I want to to remove the second and third occurence of `Speaker 1:` but keep the first and fourth one via regex.
I tried using `(Speaker 1:)(.|\n)*((Speaker 1:))(.|\n)*(Speaker 2:)` to be able to access the groups but this didn't work out.
How can I access only the repeated lines containing `Speaker 1:` which are followed by `Speaker 2:`?

Comment: Sorry - typo. It's always either "Speaker 1:" or "Speaker 2:"

Comment: This is probably not a good tool for a regular expression. You'll have much better results writing a short program.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a capture group to keep the first occurrence.

Then match all consecutive parts that start with the same `Speaker` , digits and `:` using a backreference.

In the replacement use group 1 to keep the first occurrence.

```
^((Speaker \d+:)(?:\n(?!Speaker ).*)*)(?:\n\2(?:\n(?!Speaker ).*)*)*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(Speaker \d+:)` Capture **group 2** Match Speaker and 1+ digits
  - `(?:\n(?!Speaker ).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `Speaker`
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n\2` Match a newline and a backreference to group 1
  - `(?:\n(?!Speaker ).*)*` Match a newline and all lines that do not start with `Speaker`
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rtBvsX/1)